# How to calculate ARGB an RGB for 64x64px

Tags: c#, rgb, argb

Im trying to change  this [program](https://github.com/ottools/ItemEditor/) its item editor for sprites in size 32x32px
in i want to swap from  32x32px to 64px x 64px

I have something like this

[Source](https://github.com/ottools/ItemEditor/blob/2bccd9e5396e742c2403658281b85b4c577570db/Source/PluginInterface/Sprite.cs#L50):

```
public const byte DefaultSize = 32;
public const ushort RGBPixelsDataSize = 3072; // 32*32*3
public const ushort ARGBPixelsDataSize = 4096; // 32*32*4
```

i changed to

```
public const byte DefaultSize = 64;
public const ushort RGBPixelsDataSize = 12288; // 64*64*3
public const ushort ARGBPixelsDataSize = 16384; // 64*64*4
```

next

i in 32 version i have

[Source](https://github.com/ottools/ItemEditor/blob/2bccd9e5396e742c2403658281b85b4c577570db/Source/PluginInterface/Item.cs#L313):

```
for (int y = 0; y < Sprite.DefaultSize; ++y)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < Sprite.DefaultSize; ++x)
    {
        rgbaData[128 * y + x * 4 + 0] = rgbData[(32 - y - 1) * 96 + x * 3 + 2]; // blue
        rgbaData[128 * y + x * 4 + 1] = rgbData[(32 - y - 1) * 96 + x * 3 + 1]; // green
        rgbaData[128 * y + x * 4 + 2] = rgbData[(32 - y - 1) * 96 + x * 3 + 0]; // red
        rgbaData[128 * y + x * 4 + 3] = 0;
    }
}
```

so i have now question:

i should change to ?

i don't know how to calculate this

```
for (int y = 0; y < Sprite.DefaultSize; ++y)

    {
    for (int x = 0; x < Sprite.DefaultSize; ++x)
        {
            rgbaData[256 * y + x * 4 + 0] = rgbData[(64 - y - 1) * 192 + x * 3 + 2]; // blue
            rgbaData[256 * y + x * 4 + 1] = rgbData[(64 - y - 1) * 192 + x * 3 + 1]; // green
            rgbaData[256 * y + x * 4 + 2] = rgbData[(64 - y - 1) * 192 + x * 3 + 0]; // red
            rgbaData[256 * y + x * 4 + 3] = 0;
        }
    }
```

I trying with 256, and program work but saved ARGB is black or transparent im not sure.
RGB is working property properly. I can se image in RGB. but nor in ARGB
...

and this

[Source](https://github.com/ottools/ItemEditor/blob/2bccd9e5396e742c2403658281b85b4c577570db/Source/PluginInterface/Sprite.cs#L96):

```
for (int i = 0; i < chunkSize; ++i)
{
    // Transparent pixel
    rgb32x32x3[96 * y + x * 3 + 0] = transparentColor;
    rgb32x32x3[96 * y + x * 3 + 1] = transparentColor;
    rgb32x32x3[96 * y + x * 3 + 2] = transparentColor;
    x++;
    if (x >= 32)
    {
        x = 0;
        ++y;
    }
}
```

change to

```
for (int i = 0; i < chunkSize; ++i)
{
    // Transparent pixel
    rgb32x32x3[192 * y + x * 3 + 0] = transparentColor;
    rgb32x32x3[192 * y + x * 3 + 1] = transparentColor;
    rgb32x32x3[192 * y + x * 3 + 2] = transparentColor;
    x++;
    if (x >= 64)
    {
        x = 0;
        ++y;
    }
}
```

How to calculate argbData?

Comment: Gotta say why have a public const `DefaultSize` when you don't use it at all places... eg. `if (x >= 32)` should have been `if (x >= Sprite.DefaultSize)` - now you need to check all the code

Comment: I was checked all code , find all "32"  and i checkd line by line

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in PluginInterface.dll
index out of range in this place `rgbaData[256 * y + x * 4 + 0] = rgbData[(64 - y - 1) * 192 + x * 3 + 2]; // blue`

Comment: I added links to the github source, so that others don't need to search for the relevant code in github project - pls check if I linked the correct source code and change if appropiat

Comment: I guess, because you didn't need to change 96 - 96 is the dpi which doesn't change when going from 32x32 to 64x64.

Comment: Thanks for help, i tryied [256 * y + x * 4 + 0] = rgbData[(64 - y - 1) * 96 + x * 3 + 2]; and program don't throw any errors. But ARGB is still black/transparent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254703/discussion-between-dodr-and-rand-random).

Comment: sorry, offline for sometime (lunch break) so no chatting for me

Comment: @RandRandom No, 96 in this case is the stride. The DPI never plays a part when working with the pixel buffers directly. The stride just happens to have the same value as the common DPI in this specific case.

Answer (score 2):

It will help to understand how image pixels are stored. Each pixel is 4 bytes in rgba, and 3 bytes in rgb. Pixels are stored row major. The number of bytes in each row of pixels is called the 'stride'. In this case the stride is `imageWidth * bytesPerPixel`, but it does not have to be, for most image formats the stride is an explicit image parameter.

So

> 128 * y + x * 4 + 0

breaks down int

`<stride> * y + x * <bytesPerPixel> + <channel>`

> rgbaData[128 * y + x * 4 + 0] = rgbData[(32 - y - 1) * 96 + x * 3 + 2];

The `(32 - y - 1)` part will cause the rows to be mirrored in the horizontal plane. I.e. The bottom row of the input will be copied to the top row of the output. The different channels will also change the image from BGR to RGB, or vice versa.

> rgbaData[128 * y + x * 4 + 3] = 0;

This looks highly suspect to me, since it will presumably set the alpha channel to zero, i.e. fully transparent, and that just seem wrong to me.

I'm not sure what the specific purpose of your program is, as far as I can see it is a correct conversion from 32x32 images to 64x64 images. But if the only purpose is to convert from RGB to RGBA it should probably set the Alpha channel to fully visible, and not do anything like flipping rgb-order or mirroring the image. So I would check that the pixel format of the output buffer is correct.

I would also suggest writing code that is size agnostic, i.e. take the image size as a parameter rather than hard coding values.If you are unsure about the order the rgba values should be in, try setting a channel to byte.MaxValue, and verify with a image editing program that the correct channel was affected. I'm often confused about the order of the channels myself, it does not help that some places use RGB and some use BGR to mean the same exact thing.

Comment: I thought changing to 64px would be easier. Now it turned out that the RGB sprites are not visible properly. I think I'm giving up.. but thanks for your help.
Maybe I'll sit down to it again in the evening calmly